# how to turn multiple tables in a text file into one table with an additional column?

Tags: r, readline

My text file "myfile.txt" contains many tables with the same columns (name, age, weight, profession). It looks like:

```
table_ID 001  
John | 38 | 165 | Computer scientist  
Mary | 22 | 122 | Student  

table_ID 002  
Patric| 44 | 105 | Teacher  
Kim | 56 | 155 | Salesman  
Kate | 33 | 133 | Student  
...

table_ID 100  
Peter| 44 | 105 | Teacher  
Han | 56 | 155 | Salesman  
Ken | 33 | 133 | Student  

I want to output a data.frame with an additional column ("table_ID"), which looks like:

table_ID name age weight profession  
001 John  38  165  Computer scientist  
001 Mary  22  122  Student  
002 Patric 44 105  Teacher  
002 Kim  56  155   Salesman  
002 Kate 33  133   Student  
...

100 Peter 44 105 Teacher  
100 Han  56  155 Salesman  
100 Ken 33  133  Student
```

How do I do it in R? Many thanks.

Comment: Do you have this `|` in your `myfile.txt'

Comment: Akrun, thank you for your magic tricks! Actually my table_ID is not as simple as it shows above, they are kind of irregular: NM_000775, NM_001014975, NM_001080484, etc. The common thing is the character string "table_ID" in front of them. How do you deal with this situation?

Comment: Updated the solution.  I copy/pasted the input data and saved as a file.  It seems to work for me.  Hope it work for your original data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
library(tidyr) 
lines <- readLines('paul.txt')
indx <- grepl('table_ID', lines)
lst <- split(lines, cumsum(indx))
names(lst) <- sub('\\D+', '', sapply(lst,`[`, 1))
res <- unnest(lapply(lst, function(x)
     read.table(text=x[-1], header=FALSE, sep="|")), table_ID)
```